# How to create Koa2 middleware which will modify response body and run last in a chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa2

I have a Koa2 application, which renders templates on different routes. I'd like to introduce a middleware which will modify rendered templates in some way and I need it to be the last in a chain of other middlewares. Are there any way to enforce some middleware to be applied *last* before firing response using Koa2 and without modification of the already defined routes?

I have tried the code below:

```javascript
// modification middleware
app.use(async function (ctx, next) {
  await next();
  ctx.body = ctx.body.toUpperCase();
})

// template rendering
app.use(async function (ctx, next) {
  const users = [{ }, { name: 'Sue' }, { name: 'Tom' }];
  await ctx.render('content', {
    users
  });
});

app.listen(7001);
```

It works as expected, but if any other middleware will be introduced before the `modification` one, it will be not the last in the chain.

Is it possible to achieve described behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out solution to this question sometime ago. In case someone else will need to do something like in the question, here's the code:

```js
// modification middleware
const mw = async function(ctx, next) {
  await next();
  ctx.body = ctx.body.toUpperCase();
}

app.middleware.unshift(mw);
```

Basically `middleware` member of the application object can be accessed externally. Using standard array method `unshift`, it can be enforced to add needed middle-ware first in middlewares array, which will be treated by Koa as the last one in chain.